# Criar uma lista de contatos e a separar em duas outras listas

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, dicionário

Tenho que criar uma lista de contatos em Python, com nome, idade e número do telefone, e depois tenho que separar em 2 listas: uma lista só com os contatos de maior de 18 anos e outra lista apenas com menor de 18 anos e imprimir na tela as 2 listas separadas em ordem alfabética.

Mas eu não estou conseguindo separar as listas, elas saem desse jeito aqui:

```
[['joao', 'maria'], [33, 12], ['1234567', '98765432']]

[['joao', 'maria'], [33, 12], ['1234567', '98765432']]
```

Mas era pra sair dessa maneira:

Lista1:

```
nome: joao, idade: 33, Numero:1234567
```

Lista2:

```
nome: maria, idade: 12, Numero:98765432
```

O código é esse:

```
contatoNome = []
contatoIdade = []
contatoNumero = []
contato = {"nome" : contatoNome, "idade" : contatoIdade, "numero" : contatoNumero}

lista1 = []
lista2 = []

entrada = ""
while entrada != "s":
    nome = input('Qual o nome? ')
    contatoNome.append(nome)
    idade = int(input('Digite a idade: '))
    contatoIdade.append(idade)
    numero = input('Digite o numero: ')
    contatoNumero.append(numero)
    entrada = input("Deseja sair? ")
    print()
    if entrada.lower() == "s":
        verificar = contato["idade"]
        for n in verificar:
            if n > 18:
                 lista1.append(contatoNome)#{"nome" : contatoNome, "idade" : contatoIdade, "numero" : contatoNumero}
                 lista1.append(contatoIdade)
                 lista1.append(contatoNumero)
            else:
                lista2.append(contatoNome)  # {"nome" : contatoNome, "idade" : contatoIdade, "numero" : contatoNumero}
                lista2.append(contatoIdade)
                lista2.append(contatoNumero)
        print()
        print(lista1)
        print()
        print(lista2)
```

Comment: Se você já tem o dict `contato ` por que não o usa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suas listas `contatoNome`, `contatoIdade` e `contatoNumero` estão guardando todos os valores, então não adianta adicioná-las em `lista1` e `lista2`, pois aí ambas terão todos os valores também.

Na verdade eu sugiro rever a forma como está estruturando os dados. Se o nome, idade e número estão relacionados (se todas as informações referem-se à mesma pessoa), faz mais sentido mantê-las juntas, em vez de ter listas separadas.

Uma opção seria criar uma [tupla](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) para cada pessoa, e guardar essas tuplas em uma lista:

```
# lista que guarda todos os contatos
contatos = []

while True:
    nome = input('Qual o nome? ')
    idade = int(input('Digite a idade: '))
    numero = input('Digite o numero: ')
    # adiciona a tupla (nome, idade, numero) na lista de contatos
    contatos.append((nome, idade, numero))
    entrada = input("Deseja sair?\n")
    if entrada.lower() == "s":
        break # sai do while

maiores = []
menores = []
# separa os contatos por idade
for contato in contatos:
    if contato[1] > 18:
        maiores.append(contato)
    else:
        menores.append(contato)

print(maiores)
print(menores)
```

Repare que eu fiz `contatos.append((nome, idade, numero))`: esses parênteses parecem redundantes, mas não são.
Se eu fizesse apenas `contatos.append(nome, idade, numero)` daria erro, porque o método  `append` estaria recebendo 3 parâmetros (mas ele só recebe 1). Ao colocar um par de parênteses a mais, estou criando uma tupla contendo o nome, idade e número, e essa tupla é que está sendo inserida na lista `contatos`.

Ao final do `while`, a lista `contatos` terá várias tuplas, cada uma referindo-se aos dados de uma pessoa.

Depois é só fazer um loop em `contatos` e filtrar de acordo com a idade, inserindo a pessoa na respectiva lista.

Se quiser mostrar os dados em ordem alfabética do nome, basta usar [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) e definir o critério de ordenação (que entendo que será o nome):

```
def getnome(contato):
    return contato[0]

print(sorted(maiores, key=getnome))
print(sorted(menores, key=getnome))
```

E claro que, uma vez tendo os dados que você precisa, você pode imprimir da maneira que quiser. Por exemplo:

```
print('maiores de 18:')
for nome, idade, fone in sorted(maiores, key=getnome):
    print(f'nome: {nome}, idade: {idade}, fone: {fone}')
```

Mas aí já é questão de formatação, pois o mais importante (separar os dados corretamente) já foi resolvido.

---

Outra opção é guardar os dados em [dicionários](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) em vez de tuplas:

```
# lista que guarda todos os contatos
contatos = []

while True:
    nome = input('Qual o nome? ')
    idade = int(input('Digite a idade: '))
    numero = input('Digite o numero: ')
    # adiciona um dicionário na lista de contatos
    contatos.append({ 'nome': nome, 'idade': idade, 'numero': numero })
    entrada = input("Deseja sair?\n")
    if entrada.lower() == "s":
        break # sai do while

maiores = []
menores = []
# separa os contatos por idade
for contato in contatos:
    if contato['idade'] > 18:
        maiores.append(contato)
    else:
        menores.append(contato)

def getnome(contato):
    return contato['nome']

print(sorted(maiores, key=getnome))
print(sorted(menores, key=getnome))

# ou, mostrando os dados de outra maneira:
print('maiores de 18:')
for contato in sorted(maiores, key=getnome):
    print(f'nome: {contato["nome"]}, idade: {contato["idade"]}, fone: {contato["numero"]}')

# repita para a lista menores (ou crie uma função para imprimir os dados)
```

Independente da forma escolhida (tupla ou dicionário), o importante é que agora todas as informações de uma pessoa estão juntas em uma única estrutura (cada tupla ou dicionário representa uma pessoa), o que fica bem melhor na hora de trabalhar com os dados: em vez de ficar "caçando" informações em listas diferentes, você tem tudo em um elemento só.

Comment: Agora deu tudo certo, vlw obrigado \o/ Realmente a minha estrutura não estava boa.